# Unable to parse date <inputdate> using 'M/d/yy' (M <> d) in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I m stuck with saving my post date in magento.when i try to save date it gives error like

[image]

I have used below code to parse date for save.

```
$date1 = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($data['valid_upto'], Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT);
            $validdate = $date1->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

one thing that same code is using for my other site for same functionality its working fine.

can any one have idea why this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Got the answer.There was diffrent locale selected for my store.
Select your store from top left corner and change you locale to fit your date format.

```
System->Configuration->General

Locale Option->Select your Locale
```